# "Shot" or "shooted"

Tags: grammar

Which is correct: *shot* or *shooted*? Where and when is the form *shooted* used?

Comment: Related: [“Troubleshooted” or “troubleshot”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3060/troubleshooted-or-troubleshot)

Comment: I've never come across *shooted* as a past participle in the *transitive* form. *He shooted the gun* sounds like baby-talk to me. But I've no problem with saying *My bean sprouts have shooted", for example.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Shooted** is an obsolete, nonstandard simple past tense and past participle of shoot. [(source)](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/shooted)

You should not use this form. *Shot* is proper.

It's still used sometimes, but it's really obsolete. Example:

> He took his gun and shooted people just like, from one block of LePlaza and two blocks from the main police station of PAP.

— [The Huffington Post](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/georgianne-nienaber/senator-leahy-calls-for-f_b_795356.html), “Georgianne Nienaber: Senator Leahy Calls for Freeze on Haiti Aid, Clinton Silent, Palin Visits Camps”

It's also *common* to use shooted when asking:

> Have you ever shooted a gun?

Although it's also improper and the correct term is "Have you ever shot a gun?"

Comment: It's also common to use shooted when asking:

where did you find it?

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: how do you know "It's also common to use shooted when asking:

    Have you ever shooted a gun?"

Comment: I've just heard people use it once in a while :) still, it doesn't make it proper in any way and you should avoid it unless you have a perfectly good reason to form it like that.

Comment: u mean "perfectly good reason" as mentioned above? (about shooting sprouts) LOL

Comment: lol, no, I mean for example if you're writing lyrics for a song and you need a line to rhyme the previous line, you could possibly do this, if you have no other way to avoid it :)

Comment: thanks, now I kind of understand what it stands for and I will never use it :D

Comment: Great. Just to remind you, if your question is resolved, you should mark the answer as accepted by clicking the tick mark by the left side of the post. Good luck on the site!

Answer (score 4):

It's related to usage.

Shooted is used when speaking of plants sending out shoots (My lilies have shooted). It's usually intransitive.

Shot is used in most other contexts. It can be transitive (I shot the sheriff) or intransitive (The kids shot out of class as soon as the bell rang).

Comment: If can add a comment to my own post, all the intransitive uses of shot that I can think of require a preposition after the verb, making shot into a phrasal verb eg shot out, shot away, etc.

Answer (score 1):

*Shot* is the correct past tense of *shoot*. *Shot* is also a noun referring to the firing of a gun or the projectile that is blasted out of one.

Comment: do you mean that this is THE ONLY right varient? no exceptions? what about these http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Special%3ASearch&search=shooted

Comment: http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=shooted

Comment: @qweqwe: Truly, the Intertubes are a seething cauldron of slang and bad English.

Comment: @qweqwe: The only legitimate way to use "shooted" is in its nominal meaning of "having shoots" as a plant has shoots. The valid Wikipedia uses you link to refer to things like "green-shoooted plants" and the like. There are misuses of past tense as there well. Wikipedia is not without its share of mistakes in fact and English, in case you weren't aware.